# Is it necessary to scale the data after box-cox transformation

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, data-transform

I have a problem. When I did regression analysis using SVR with a linear kernel, I found that the dependent(target value) were not normally distributed and had a long tail on the left side. So I used box-cox transformation. Then the visualization of the target value is like this:
[the distribution of the data before and after box-cox transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7LcE.png)

The data were normally distributed now, but the number was getting larger.
Most of the variables in my dataset are range from 0 to 1. If I want to train a model which will perform well, shall I scale(e.g. using MinMax Scaler) the data after the box-cox transformation, in order to narrow the gap between the variables and target value?

Comment: Note that the target value being non-gaussian is not necessarily a problem, the key thing for MSE-based modeling is conditional guassianity (what a word! :-) ).

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean the transformation on target value is not always necessary?

Comment: Probably this question should migrate to [Corss Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)?